# Rectangle collision - Unwanted overlapping. (Processing IDE)

Tags: java, processing, collision-detection, collision

So I have this simple processing sketch where blocks follow the mouse. It has a basic collision function which detects an intersection between two rectangles then sets rectangle A's position equal to rectangle B's position minus rectangle A's width (assuming rect B is in front of A). Unfortunately this method is insufficient and the rectangles overlap each other slightly. I really want the rectangles to line up perfectly as if they were a strip of rectangles. Is there a way to do this? Here is my runnable sketch below:

```
class Block {
  color c = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  float x = random(width);
  float speed = random(3, 6);
  void run() {
    float dir = mouseX - x;
    dir /= abs(dir);
    x += dir * speed;
    fill(c);
    rect(x, 300, 30, 60);
  }
  void collide() {
    for (Block other : blocks) {
      if (other != this) {
        if (x + 30 > other.x && x + 30 <= other.x + 15)
          x = other.x - 30;
        else if (x < other.x + 30 && x > other.x + 15)
          x = other.x + 30;
      }
    }
  }
}
Block[] blocks = new Block[6];
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++)
    blocks[i] = new Block();
}
void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (Block b : blocks) {
    b.run();
    b.collide();
  }
}
void mousePressed() {
  setup();
}
```

Comment: You're looping through your Blocks, and for each of them, you're looping through your blocks again, checking for collisions of one other block at a time. However, you never handle the situation when a block overlaps two other blocks, which is what's actually happening when you see the overlap.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on how i can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I updated your code following the multi-object collision example found in http://ejohn.org/apps/processing.js/examples/topics/bouncybubbles.html

The idea is to perform steps in this order:

1. update the position of each object according to its speed and direction
2. check for collisions and adapt position to the new constraints
3. display object

I created a new method `display()` for `Block` that is run after updating the position following a collision detection. The rectangles are not displayed in the `run()` because they would have an incorrect position.
The method `overlap()` called at setup takes care of overlapping rectangles when initializing the sketch.

Hope this helps!

```
class Block {
  color c = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  float x = random(width);
  float speed = random(3, 6);
  void run() {
    float dir = mouseX - x;
    dir /= abs(dir);
    x += dir * speed;
  }
  void display() {
    fill(c);
    rect(x, 300, 30, 60);
  }
  void collide() {
    for (Block other : blocks) {
      if (other != this) {
        if (x + 30 > other.x && x + 30 <= other.x + 15) {
          x = other.x - 30;
        }
        else if (x < other.x + 30 && x > other.x + 15) {
          x = other.x + 30;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  void overlap() {
    for (Block other : blocks) {
      if (other != this) {
        if (x + 30 > other.x && x + 30 <= other.x + 30) {
          x = other.x - 30;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
Block[] blocks = new Block[6];
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    blocks[i] = new Block();
  }
   for (Block b : blocks) {
     b.overlap();
   }
}
void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (Block b : blocks) {
   b.run();
   b.collide();
   b.display();
  }
}
void mousePressed() {
  setup();
}
```

PS also added some extra curly brackets for 1-line if statements that even though unnecessary make the code more "safe"

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! So it was just a simple ordering problem. The little things *sigh*